# Compiler is giving errors when I try to print the contents of a vector?

Tags: c++, templates, vector

Basically, I have a .h file, in which I have defined a function to generate an element buffer and squashed list of vertices (for OpenGL) given an unoptimized list of vertices. I ran into some problems though, and it turns out that I can't actually access the contents of a vector which I pass to the method. My code is as follows

```
#ifndef LEARNOPENGL_COMMON_H
#define LEARNOPENGL_COMMON_H

#include "ContextBase.h" // this includes all the OpenGL stuff
#include "vector"
#include "iostream"

class common {
public:

    template<typename V>
    static bool are_equal(int size, V* v1, V* v2) {
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            //if (v1[x] != v2[x]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    template<typename V, typename E>
    static void GenOptimizedArrays(const int vertex_size, std::vector<V>* vertex_source,
                                   std::vector<V>* vertex_out, std::vector<E>* ebo_out) {

        std::vector<V> * vertex_vector = new std::vector<V>();
        std::vector<E> * element_vector = new std::vector<E>();

        std::cout << vertex_source[0] << std::endl;
    }
};

#endif //LEARNOPENGL_COMMON_H
```

However, my compiler is telling me that trying to print (access?) `vertex_source[0]` is causing an error- the exact (relevant) error message is

```
error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}
’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&
```

I tried to search this online but, while I found similar problems, everything just said to use an iterator without explaining *why* I figured out how from the solutions, but found no good explanation. Can you help on this?

Comment: vertex_source is a pointer, not a vector, so your code is the same as cout << *vertex_source. Does the problem seem obvious then?

Comment: Maybe you wanted to use references? like this: `static void GenOptimizedArrays( const int vertex_size, const std::vector<V>& vertex_source, std::vector<V>& vertex_out, std::vector<E>& ebo_out)` this way you can skip the vectors alloocations...

Comment: @QuestionC painfully so. Thank you

Comment: It's usually a mistake to use `new` with containers.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<int> *vec = new vector<int>;
//std::cout<<vec[0];(1)
std::cout<<&vec[0];(2)
```

If you uncomment (1) and run above snippet you will get almost same error. Variable `vec` knows only about its address unless you assign data into its pointer location. So when you try to access the data from its pointer location system can't bind it with stream.

If you try to print the address as shown in(2) it will print the address of the location variable `vec` knows.